# How can I get the data from hidden field in jQuery? (hidden field has class in place of id)

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, click, field

I am getting data from the database:

```
<table>
    <?php
    $select_data = mysql_query(" select * from `data_table` ") or die(mysql_error());
    while($data_row = mysql_fetch_array($select_data))
    {
   ?>
   <tr>
      <td> 
         <img src="../Stuff-site_data_images/<?php echo$data_row['data_image_name']?>" width="100" height="100" /> 
      </td>
      <td> <?php echo $data_row['data_image_name'];?> </td>
      <td> <?php echo $data_row['data_description'];?> </td>
```

I want to get data from here:

```
      <td align="center" class="row_id">
          <input class="inner_row_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $data_row['data_id'];?>" name="show_detail_button" id="show_detail_button"> Show All
      </td>
```

I want to get data from here:

```
      </tr>
     <?php
     } 
     ?>
</table>
```

so as far as I know jQuery will conflict when there is more than 1 id so that's why I used CSS class names `"row_id" & "inner_row_id"`. 
When I click on `"row_id"` I want the value of `"inner_row_id"`
and for that I have written the code below:

```
        $(".row_id").click(function(e){
            var row_id = $(".inner_row_id").val();
            alert("Le click thyuu....");
        });
```

Is there any one who suggest me what to do in this...

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: I want to get data from hidden field which has the value from DataBase

Comment: from this portion: <input class="inner_row_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $data_row['data_id'];?>" name="show_detail_button" id="show_detail_button"> Show All

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
$(".row_id").click(function(e){
  alert($(this).find('.inner_row_id').val()); 
})
```

The "click" function gives you access to this, which is the element that you clicked on.  Find then looks for any decedents of the element which have class .inner_row_id.

[Link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cm4gyuum/)

Comment: Could you put the generated HTML into your question as well as the expected results?

Answer (score 0):

As I see you are creating the input dynamically so use below JS:

```
$(".row_id").on('click',function(e){
  var row_id = $(this).children('.inner_row_id').val();
  alert("Le click thyuu....");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7entyr5w/).